# How do i directly show that $\text{rng} (T)$ is $F$ where $T$ is a trace over a field $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:M_{n\times n} (F) \rightarrow F : A\mapsto \text{tr}(A)$.

I can explicitly find a basis for $\ker (T)$, so that $\text{nullity}(T)=n^2 -1$.

Then, by dimension theorem, $\text{rng}(T)$ must be equal to $F$, but how do i show this directly?

If $F$ is infinite, this is trivial, but what if $F$ is finite? Say $F$ is of characteristic $n$ and fix $a\in F$ such that $a$ is nonzero. Then $\frac{1}{n}$ does not exist. How do i show that $F\subset \text{rng}(T)$ directly?

Answer (score 1):

Show that $T$ is linear, and has at least one non-zero value. Then deduce from linearity that $T$ is surjective.

Or, show that for every $x\in F$ the matrix which has $x$ in the top-left corner and zero elsewhere, has trace $x$.

Comment: No problem. I see you switched from analysis without choice to linear algebra without choice. :-)

Comment: Yes, i couldn't proceed my study on analysis since i didn't know linear algebra. I will get back to analysis sooner or later :)

Comment: Yes, linear algebra is important. Good luck!